# Cross platform xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

As you know there is one shared project across all other projects like `UWP`, `android` and `ios` and there is file called `MainPage.xaml`. From my understanding this is the common ide template for all added projects. That's fine. My question is for instance for `UWP` project which also contains `MainPage.xaml`. Let's assume i want to differentiate some UI elements only for this UWP project. Should i use somehow this `MainPage.xaml` belonging to `UWP` project or what should i do? Hope my question is clear.

Comment: the MainPage file in the UWP is really just used to bootstrap the shared Forms application on the UWP platform (iOS uses AppDelegate, Android uses MainActivity).  There are a variety of mechanisms for customizing the UI per platform, and none of them rely on MainPage.

Comment: If you want to implement some UI performance specific in UWP(or Android,or iOS).You can use CustomRenderer or DependencyService.Refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/

Comment: There's many ways to do this.  However; if the view is only valid and will only ever be valid for UWP then it should be in the UWP project.  I wouldn't put it in MainPage.xaml of that project directly but as a new view (UserControl) of that project.

Comment: @MichaelPuckettII but how to say for UWp project to use his own mainPage raather than shared mainPage? And is it not breaking rules mainPage from shared is for all projects?

Comment: You can use Device.OS to determine the type of device ... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/device ... that means no need for custom renderer IF that can fit your requirement. You can stay within the Forms framework but provide a different experience per device type.

Comment: I said "I wouldn't"